# Find the eigenvalues of the block matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> The eigenvalues of the following block matrix $$\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 &0 &0 &1 \\ 0 &0&0 &0 &1&0  \\ 0 &0&0 &1 &0&0 \\ 1&0&0&0&0&0\\0&1&0&0&0&0 \\ 0&0&1&0&0&0 \end{pmatrix}$$ are
>
> 1. $ \ 1 \ $
> 2. $-1$
> 3. $ \ i $
> 4. $-i$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\mathrm R_3$ be the $3 \times 3$ [exchange matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exchange_matrix)

$$\mathrm R_3 := \begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 & 1\\0 & 1 & 0\\1 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$$

whose characteristic polynomial is

$$p (s) := (s-1)^2 (s+1)$$

Hence, the characteristic polynomial of the given $6 \times 6$ permutation matrix is

$$\det \begin{bmatrix} s \,\mathrm I_3 & -\mathrm R_3\\ -\mathrm I_3 & s \,\mathrm I_3\end{bmatrix} = \det \left( s^2 \mathrm I_3 - \mathrm R_3 \right) = p (s^2)$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint : This is a [permutation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_matrix) $P$. **Note that the components of a vector does not change except its order**. The definition of an eigenvector is $Pv=\lambda v$. Now look at the components of $v$, what does it say about $\lambda$?

Comment: Sorry, I suddenly realize that my argument only shows that $|\lambda|=1$, which is of no help to your current problem. I think @Rodrigo de Azevedo answer is the correct (and maybe the most efficient way) to do this problem. He study the block matrix eigenvalue.